# Why print command gives a new line even though there is no data to print

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Just typing `print` only gives newline in python.  Typing `print` without the brackets in 3.x will also gives a newline. Why?

Comment: Try reading the documentation? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) says so

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`
>
> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed by end. sep, end and file, if present, must be given as keyword arguments.
>
> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream, separated by sep and followed by end. Both sep and end must be strings; they can also be None, which means to use the default values. **If no objects are given, `print()` will just write `end`.**
>
> The file argument must be an object with a write(string) method; if it is not present or None, sys.stdout will be used. Since printed arguments are converted to text strings, print() cannot be used with binary mode file objects. For these, use file.write(...) instead.
>
> Whether output is buffered is usually determined by file, but if the flush keyword argument is true, the stream is forcibly flushed.
>
> Changed in version 3.3: Added the flush keyword argument.

Note that `end` is defaulted to `'\n'` which is a new line.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, print is now a function. It will print a new line character at the end of your statement.

If you don't specify an "end" it will by default use a new line character.

You can prevent this by doing something such as:

```
print("hello world", end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting how languages differ in this.

`print` in the Korn shell (ksh) has the same behaviour as `python`, i.e. it adds a newline.  Bash does not have a `print`, relying on `echo` instead, which also adds a newline (which, like python, can be suppressed).

`print` in Perl does not, and caused so much inconvenience that another version, called `say`, was added which does add a newline.

Ruby and PHP are like Perl in that `print` also does not add a newline.  This of course is less of an issue when embedded in HTML.

If you look at other languages, for example [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HelloWorldInManyProgrammingLanguages) you will find opinion divided as to whether a newline should be added or not.  The removal of the newline in Python is discussed in [PEP259](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0259/).

Answer (score 1):

Because the default parameter in print is \n for the end, 
though if you pass parameter for print end variable as \t or space , then you can see the same !

But it works 2.7 and above!